# Sending POST request with body in netty

Tags: java, http, netty

I want to do POST request to some API by netty. Request must contains parameters as `form-data` in body. How I try to do this:

```
   FullHttpRequest httpRequest = new DefaultFullHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, POST, url);
   httpRequest.setUri("https://url.com/myurl");
   ByteBuf byteBuf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(myParameters, Charset.defaultCharset());
   httpRequest.headers().set(ACCEPT_ENCODING, GZIP);
   httpRequest.headers().set(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
   httpRequest.headers().set(CONTENT_LENGTH, byteBuf.readableBytes());
   httpRequest.content().clear().writeBytes(byteBuf);
   Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
   b.group(group)
            .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, CNXN_TIMEOUT_MS)
            .handler(new ChannelInitializerCustomImpl());

   ChannelFuture cf = b.connect(url.getHost(), port);
   cf.addListener(new ChannelFutureListenerCustomImpl();
```

That's worked ok, but result is different from I received by `postman` or other instruments. 
What's the correct way to set my parameters as `form-data` to request body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using Apache `httpcomponents` library to create `HtppEntity`, serialize it to byte array and set to netty `ByteBuf` and also use `jackson` for parse json from String to Map:

```
    Map<String, String> jsonMapParams = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStringParams, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {});

    List<NameValuePair> formParams = jsonMapParams.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> new BasicNameValuePair(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    HttpEntity httpEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formParams);
    ByteBuf byteBuf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(EntityUtils.toByteArray(httpEntity));

    httpRequest.headers().set(ACCEPT_ENCODING, GZIP);
    httpRequest.headers().set(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpRequest.headers().set(CONTENT_LENGTH, byteBuf.readableBytes());
    httpRequest.content().clear().writeBytes(byteBuf);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your request header is not set correct, to set content_type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and have a try.